# How to edit menu in header - wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need help on how to start editing the header on my wordpress site.I am using google chrome and the developers tool. I am a bit lost on how to pick out css properties and edit them myself and would appreciate some help.

[The URL to my site](http://www.shopstuff.se/nyheter/)
I want it to look like the [wordpress header](http://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/)

When you hover over it I want it to display an opacity and when you click on it I want it to mark the whole "Square".

The CSS I am using for my menu is:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 15px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
transition: background 0.3s;
}

.navbar-nav > li.active > a {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the margin from the a elements

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 15px;
}
```

Once you hover the navigation item you add a semi transparent background. You can also add a transition to add a "fade" animation.

```
#wpo-mainnav.navbar ul.nav > li:hover > a {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
transition: background 0.3s;
}
```

To mark the current category just add a background to that item.

```
#wpo-mainnav.navbar ul.nav > li.active > a {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

*** EDIT ***

Your navigation items have an :active styling, try adding this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
color: #434a54;
}
```

Stylesheets being used:

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried your changes but unfortunately nothing happend. I have edited my answer so you can see what I have done.

Comment: I just noticed you have various stylesheets, try the code from my updated answer @Joneskvist

Comment: It works now, wonderful mister. To change the light-colour when you hover, like wordpress has, do I modify `0.8`?

Comment: Yeah in rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), the first three numbers correspond to the actual color (in the this case #FFF / White). 0.8 is the opacity/transparency. @Joneskvist

Comment: Kudos to you for helping me understand. By the way could you please explain how you concluded that I have various spreadsheets? One more thing, when you press on a category on the menu and remove the mouse from the menu, the text disappears [link](http://www.shopstuff.se/produkt-kategori/lek-spel/), how come :) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69465/discussion-between-joneskvist-and-chrisbedoya).

Answer (score 0):

The background color that you are looking to modify is on the list element (`li`) not the anchor element (`a`). I suppose you could use the anchor element but it doesn't take up the whole height of your navigation bar and that might not be the look you want. WordPress will add the class of `.active` to the menu item that corresponds to the current page.

```css
#main-menu > li:hover,
#main-menu > .active {
     background-color: #8ACEEC;
}
```

As a side note, try to use `!important` sparingly. It should more or less only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Hi, oh I understand so it is the `li` I should adjust! So are you sudgesting just to just paste the code you provided me with into my css sheet?

Comment: I tried doing that also but no luck. Maybe i inserted the `!important`-tag wrong?

Comment: It works. The only thing I can think of is that you have not included your CSS properly. Whether that's not at all or an overriding style due to the cascade or specificity, I have no clue.